# How can one debug embedded code in razor pages?

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor, webassembly

I am looking at Blazor client side with asp.net hosting. So I am going through the template project and Visual Studio Preview does not seem to support breakpoints in razor pages, more specifically the code block:

> ```
> @code {
>    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;
>
>    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
>    {
>        forecasts = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast"); //breakpoint here
>    }
>
> }
> ```

Is there a workaround or maybe something I am missing?
Thank you!

Comment: That could explain the issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 2):

Blazor Webassembly debugging is currently available only using Chrome browser debugging proxy. The steps are described in [Blazor docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.0#procedure):

> 1. Run a Blazor WebAssembly app in Debug configuration.
> 2. Pass the `--configuration Debug` option to the dotnet run command: `dotnet run --configuration Debug`
> 3. Access the app in the browser.
> 4. Place the keyboard focus on the app, not the developer tools panel. The developer tools panel can be closed when debugging is initiated.
> 5. Select the following Blazor-specific keyboard shortcut:

- `Shift+Alt+D` on Windows/Linux
- `Shift+Cmd+D` on macOS

> 5. Follow the steps listed on the screen to restart the browser with remote debugging enabled.
> 6. Select the following Blazor-specific keyboard shortcut once again to start the debug session:

- `Shift+Alt+D` on Windows/Linux
- `Shift+Cmd+D` on macOS

The "Hit F5 in Visual studio" debugging experience is not ready yet. Bits of it have been demonstrated by Daniel Roth in the [.NET community standup video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaemestFrt0&feature=youtu.be&t=3207). Basically, Visual studio can attach to the browser's debugging proxy. Currently, in the preview versions, you have to do a series of steps manually, while in the future, those should be streamlined and done by the Visual studio.

#### Update March 26, 2020

Microsoft released a new preview of WASM Blazor and an improved support for debugging in Visual studio. [Details here.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-3-release-now-available/)

Comment: You may want to edit the last update date to 2020 ;)